# In /etc/pam.d/sshd, what does "# [1]" mean?

Tags: 14.04, pam

In the PAM configuration file /etc/pam.d/sshd, there are a few lines ending in `# [1]`; for example:

`session    optional     pam_motd.so # [1]`

This doesn't seem to appear in any of the other PAM config files. What looks like a corresponding line in /etc/pam.d/login is simply:

`session    optional   pam_motd.so`

What does the `# [1]` mean in the sshd file? I couldn't find an explanation in the pam or pam.d manpages. I suspect it isn't a comment because Vim isn't highlighting it the same as the other comments in that file. Besides, it isn't very meaningful as a comment.

Comment: Could it be a reference to a note in the man page?